# Is there any standard which defines keycodes and/or keysyms?

Tags: keyboard, standards, xlib, keycode

I look for some standard which defines some table, which first column contains key (what we see on keyboard (`;:ж`)(`fа`)(`+=`)) and second one contains numeric representation of this key. Does this standard exist?

Also I look for standard which connects Unicode(or at least ASCII) symbols and their numeric representation ((yeah, it is UTF-8/-16/etc) but in code I need to define what the symbol user has written by his keyboard, and different libs (in JS, or Xlib for Unix-systems) do it definitely differently, but I even do not know how).

It seems a bit weird and stupid, but my final target is get keycode from keyboard and calculate the symbol. Please make it clear for me!

P.S. Sorry for my english, thank you in advance!

Comment: Typically, the operating system does the translation of keystroke to character (or at least virtual keycode) as it has the knowledge of the keyboard hardware and user configuration, including what the user wants to use the keys for/what's printed on them. So, can your program rely on the operating system? Or, are you writing an operating system component yourself? [USB keyboard info](https://www.usb.org/sites/default/files/documents/hut1_12v2.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, there are no standards like what I need. There are several half-standards intended by different companies which product keyboards, but they are not what I need.